# Search for Sharepoint Calendar in Outlook?

Tags: 2010, 2013, calendar, office-integration

Is it possible to browse for SharePoint calendars in Outlook without having to use the `Connect to Outlook` function on SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware Exchange has no knowledge of SharePoint so a link needs to be explicitly made (using the Connect to Outlook option)